# Count columns by status in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need count total register in a SQL table.
I have some status like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_MEASUREMENT' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '1',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_WEIGHMENT' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '2',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_DATA_ENTRY' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '3',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_PICTURES' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '4'
FROM product;
```

But when I run query , i have a same result in all columns.
What's wrong in query?

Comment: Add sample data and the rest of your query, your code should be working correctly.

Comment: @AaronDietz thanks for the pointer. you are right, his should work.. deleted answer.

Comment: What result you get on all columns? If you get 0 then you dont have those status there. Or like Obiwan say, ***those arent the status you are looking for***.

Comment: [Unable to replicate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56efe5/1) Please share some sample data where this problem is occurring.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens in mysql when an alias is a string literal instead of a quoted identifier....

Comment: @HoneyBadger that is an oddball thing about this query, but it seems to work. At least it does on sqlfiddle (link in previous comment).

Comment: In that case we definitely need the data...

Comment: @HoneyBadger Is very weird but Mysql support both as field name indicator. Learn that some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should sum instead of count and also use 0 instead of null, count will just count all the records.

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_MEASUREMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_WEIGHMENT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '2',
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_DATA_ENTRY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '3',
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'WAITING_PICTURES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '4'
FROM product;
```

Comment: Have you seen the sqlfiddle JNevill shared in the comment above?

Comment: You are wrong, `COUNT()`  doesn't count `nulls` both are the exact same queries. But I'm particularly against using `SUM()` because `COUNT()` do exactly that .. "count".

Comment: btw @PatrickArtner already post the same answer and delete when realize was the same as OP.